# не работает navigator.app.loadUrl в приложении vue.js cordova

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cordova, apk

столкнулся проблемой, не работает функция открытия ссылки в дефолтном браузере устройства из приложения на vue.js в cordova 5.4.1 (установил позднюю версию что бы монтировать под андроид 4.0.1)
таким образом пробую при клике её вызвать - при тесте в браузере естественно не дает эффекта, а вызывает в консоли ошибку т.к. это метод для нативного приложения.

```
 <div onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://google.com/', {openExternal : true});">Перейти на сайт</div>
```

но после сборки через cordova build android в приложении при клике на кнопку не происходит вообще ничего, что делать в такой ситуации? установить какой то плагин?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35144829/phonegap-navigator-app-exitapp-not-working похожая проблема, только с exitApp